# Can I develop iOS apps with a six year old apple machine?

Tags: ios

Sorry if this is posted in the wrong tag.

I am not sure how it works with Apple and their OS. If you have an old OS (6 years old) can you still develop applications on it or do I need to purchase a more recent machine?

Bonus question: Can I still use an old machine for its server certificate to develop with Xamarin on my Windows 10?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly, though more important than the age of the machine is the version of macOS that you're running and how the machine is configured. "Xcode 8.3.3 requires a Mac running macOS 10.12 or later." For sake of comparison, I had a MacBook Air with SSD and 4GB of RAM of that vintage, and it was infuriatingly slow. But if your machine is better equipped (or if you're more patient than me) then perhaps you're OK. But you can just try to install Xcode on your machine and see if it installs and whether it's too slow to be productive or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on a 6 years old iMac, so yes you can develop on your Mac. ;) Perhaps you should probably upgrade your Mac with an SSD and more RAM. I think running Windows should be no problem, too.